# ADF best practice for Dataflow in Parallel

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have one json file which has approx 200 lists which I'm passing to ForEach activity.
Which calls for `lookup` then `DataFlow` .

Currently I'm using TTL 30min AZ Integration Runtime
which took 30min to complete.

I'm want to know if i Run `Sequentially` will the `cost` differ or same as `without Sequential` `ForEach`.

What should be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a bit if you run sequentially because you'll only incur the cluster cold startup of 4 mins on the initial run. The subsequent sequential runs will then start immediately and save you ~4 mins for each one.